# Unable to pass a parameter <apex:param> to the relevant method

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Lets assume I have a Page code:

```
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allContacts}" var="c" >
            <apex:column value="{!c.id}" headervalue="ID"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.FirstName}" headervalue="First Name"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.LastName}" headervalue="Last Name"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Title}" headervalue="Title"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Company}" headervalue="Company"/>
            <apex:column>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addToRecruits}" value="Recruit">
                    <apex:param assignTo="{!leadID}" name="leadID" value="{!c.id}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

And relevant controller :

```
    public String leadID { get; set; }

    public PageReference addToRecruits() {
        System.debug('LeadID is: ' + leadID);
        List<Lead> potentialCandidate = [SELECT id, FirstName, lastName, Title, Company FROM Lead WHERE id = :leadID];   
        delete potentialCandidate;

        return null;
    }
```

It seems that I can NOT pass `leadID` to `addToRecruits()` method. Do you have any idea why is so?

**UPDATE:**

I could manage to solve it. Instead of querying using SOQL, I approached with this style:

```
public String leadID { get; set; }
public PageReference addToRecruits() {

    Lead candidate=new Lead(id=leadID);
    ....
}
```

Comment: For future Salesforce related questions, you'll probably get more attention if you post on the dedicated Stack Exchange Salesforce site at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, I just found out... I'll do that from now on ...

Comment: I see you already did so - for future reference, the same question is discussed here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/unable-to-pass-a-parameter-apexparam-to-a-relevant-method

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the infamous platform bug? where apex:param values are not always send to the controller with apex:commandButton (though they are send with apex:commandLink).

A simple overview of the issue and possible workarounds are summarised by Jeff Douglas here: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/

Answer (score 0):

Add  "rerender" attribute to apex:commandButton and its will start working - Something like
 `<apex:commandButton rerender="myForm" action="{!addToRecruits}" value="Recruit">`

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to pass parameter to controller but it will use commandLink also. I mean we need to use

- **command link and command button**

Eg:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!applyNow}" id="applybuttonLink" style="text-decoration:none">
<apex:commandButton value="Apply now"/>
<apex:param name="passId" assignTo="{!passId}" value="{!Vac.id}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller:

```
public String vacancyId{get;set;}
```